# Cross-sells on WooCommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible to add cross-sells on WooCommerce product page?
As I understand, cross-sells can be showed only on the Cart page.

Comment: This is what up-sells are. If you have specific products you want to display on the product page, use up-sells.

Comment: Except that @user771417 asked about cross-sells.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to this. In my situation, the "Related Products" section didn't make sense (as the store was already organized based on categories), so I removed the standard related products section and re-added it with the same template, but by feeding the template the cross-sells instead of the related products. The section still says "Related Products" and will look the same, but is populated with cross-sell products instead.

```
// Remove "related Products"
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );

// Show cross-sells using related template on single product page
// see https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_related_products.html#1264-1296
function wc_output_cross_sells() {
    $crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids', true );

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'columns'        => 2,
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'order'          => 'desc',
    );
    $args['related_products'] = array_map( 'wc_get_product', $crosssells );

    // Set global loop values.
    $woocommerce_loop['name']    = 'related';
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_columns', $args['columns'] );
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php', $args );
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wc_output_cross_sells', 30);
```